# How to properly connect and display data from Firebase to custom list view Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a custom `ListView` which displays my data from my Firebase but it is incorrect.

### [Image of Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1GkM.png)

[Image of Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Cpy.png)

As you can see in the images, it displays all of the data in one row "[a,ab,abc]". This is wrong because I needed it to be shown per row like this.

### a

### ab

abc

I saved the data I fetched from firebase in an array list

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I saved it using addChildEventListener

```
 mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            String string = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            arrayList.add(string);

            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

And here is how I made my custom adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    private final Activity context;
   private final Integer[] imgid;

    private final ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> arrayList, Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.customlayout);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;

        //this.itemname=itemname;
        this.imgid=imgid;


    }

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null,true);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);


        txtTitle.setText(arrayList.toString());
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);

        return rowView;

    }
}
```

then I declared the custom adapter in the OnCreate

```
customAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(Form1Main.this, arrayList, imgid);
```

Now I just need to properly iterate it vertically instead of having an output like the one in the first picture [a,ab,abc] to

a

---

ab

---

abc

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. If you have a particular code block you want to post as part of your question, copy and paste it into the post body and use the `{}` button to format it as code if it isn't formatted correctly already. Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52954409/edit).

Comment: ok tnx. i'll edit it

Comment: Please add your database structure and please also responde with @.

Comment: I just added an image of my database structure @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

I will show you a more simpler way to achieve this. So to display those values on separate lines, please use the following code:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String string = ds.getValue(String.class);
            arrayList.add(string);
            Log.d(TAG, string);
        }
        CustomListAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(Form1Main.this, arrayList, imgid);
        yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
producmDatabasetsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Please also check the logcat.

Comment: Hi Bradley! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?